# Could Label get a focus?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, focus, label

I have a one question on my university's test about C#. *Could label get a focus?* As I can see on MSDN site, all Controls can get a focus, but some of them aren't selectable. So it's seems to me that the right answer is "Label could get a focus, but couldn't be selected". Also Label has a Focus() method. Please, help me understand. Thanx.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is a `Focus()` method on Label and yes it is absolutely right it works; but behave differently. let me try to explain

A Label can be associated with some one input control, for instance a label for a user name text field, so there is concept of `Associated Control` with the label. [AssociatedControlID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.associatedcontrolid.aspx) on msdn

So you can associate an input control with a label and whenever label is selected the control passed to the associated input control.

[Example here](http://test.theatreline.com) click on Email or Password labels in login box and see what happened, similarly if you call focus method on the label the focus will passed to the associated control.

Comment: thanx a lot it's very clear. But I've not marked that answer was about .NET 2.0! So label hasn't this property there. And is it available just for ASP .NET? Anyway thank you very much.

Comment: @Daria: For WinForms, the control with the next tab index will receive the focus when you try to set the focus to a `Label` control. So say, for example, that you have a label with a tab index of 0 and a textbox with a tab index of 1. When you try to set focus to the label, the textbox will automatically get the focus.

Answer (score 9):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx):

> A control can be selected and receive
>   input focus if all the following are
>   true: the `Selectable` value of
>   `ControlStyles` is set to `true`, it is
>   contained in another control, and all
>   its parent controls are both visible
>   and enabled.

Since a [Label](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.label.aspx) control is not selectable, it cannot receive input focus, even if it inherits a `Focus()` method from `Control`. Therefore, the answer is *no*.

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. The presence of `Focus` or `CanFocus` properties is really irrelevant. The Windows API (which WinForms is based around) has a hard rule about which controls can receive the focus. A label (used for displaying *static* text) is one of those that can *never* get the focus. No exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to findo out if a control's ca get focus. Just read the

```
.CanFocus
```

property which is inherited from the Control class.

The Windows Forms controls in the following list are not selectable. Controls derived from these controls are also not selectable. (see [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx))

- Panel
- GroupBox
- PictureBox
- ProgressBar
- Splitter
- Label
- LinkLabel (when there is no link present in the control)

Also:

> The Focus method returns `true` if the
>   control successfully received input
>   focus. The control can have the input
>   focus while not displaying any visual
>   cues of having the focus. This
>   behavior is primarily observed by the
>   nonselectable controls listed below,
>   or any controls derived from them.
>
> A control can be selected and receive
>   input focus if all the following are
>   true: the `Selectable` value of
>   `ControlStyles` is set to `true`, it is
>   contained in another control, and all
>   its parent controls are both visible
>   and enabled.

If you need a Label-like control that you can focus, just use a TextBox and make it readonly. Set a few other properties (styles, not selectable etc.) and you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You will see that there is a read only property called CanFocus on a label, if you have a look at this property while debugging you will see it is false.

Every control that inherits from Control has the focus method, but that does not mean that it can be focused.

Comment: So label couldn't get a focus?

Comment: No, the label itself can't get focus even though the method is exposed

Answer (score 1):

Label does gets the focus but it escalates it to the input field specified in its "for" attribute. Like:

```
<label for="firstname">First Name</label><input type="text" name="firstname" />
```

In this scenario if you click on the label it will throw the focus to the input field "firstname" associated with it.

Comment: I think this was a C# question, not an HTML question.

Answer (score 1):

This is a year old, however I had a similar issue as the Op. In my case it was a user control that had a single label (docked at fill) on it (it has other functions behind the scenes - it is a calendar control and pops up a date picker - not the standard one - in either a panel (popunder) or a form (popup)).

The issue there was that UserControls are really intended as containers and resist focus (pushing it off to child controls) - as the label is the only child control, it stops the UserControl getting focus. Using readonly TextBox is a poor substitute as it lacks vertical alignment and must be multiline to size the height.

The reason I add the following as an answer here is because it IS possible (sorry guys who said here it is not) and I found this post and many like it that were little help when I looked. Anyway, the way to do it is to override the Label and set the SetStyle - also the OnPaint to draw a focus rectangle (I manually drew mine as DrawFocusRectangle didn't seem to do anything) - so as below:

```
internal class SelectableLabel: Label
{
    public SelectableLabel():base()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true);            
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPaint(e);

        //ControlPaint.DrawFocusRectangle(e.Graphics, ClientRectangle);
        if (!Focused) return;
        if (BorderStyle == BorderStyle.Fixed3D)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.CadetBlue, new[] { new Point(1, Height - 1), new Point(1, 1), new Point(Width - 1, 1) });
            e.Graphics.DrawLines(Pens.Aquamarine, new[] { new Point(2, Height - 1), new Point(Width - 1, Height - 1), new Point(Width - 1, 2) });
        }
        else
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Aquamarine, 0, 0, Width - 1 , Height - 1 );
        }
    }        
}
```

I am not concerning myself on whether it is accademically (purist view) right to do so, but that there are valid reasosn to allow an output control (like label) to sometimes gain focus.

Comment: For me the above code half works. If I click on the SelectableLabel it does gain focus, but it appears to be impossible to select the control by using the tab key -- it seems to be excluded from the tab order.