# Getting if a label is Focused by Timer event are not working as expected

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, label

I'm writing a method that wait some seconds and clean the label value. But it can't be cleaned if the user is with mouse on label.

The code:

```
public static void CleanIn(this Label label, int miliseconds)
        {
            Timer timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = miliseconds;
            timer.Tick += (o, e) =>
            {

                if (!label.Focused)
                {
                    label.ResetText();
                    timer.Stop();
                    timer.Dispose();
                }
            };
            timer.Start();
        }
```

The problem is: the value is cleaned independent if the mouse is on label. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Focused` property relates to whether the user has tabbed to the control, not to whether the mouse is positioned over it. You can use the [`MousePosition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseposition.aspx) property in combination with the [`PointToClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoclient.aspx) method to determine whether the mouse is over the control, like so:

```
...
Point cursor = label.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
if (!(cursor.X >= 0 && cursor.X <= label.Width
        && cursor.Y >= 0 && cursor.Y <= label.Height))
{
    ...
```

Comment: How to use it? I tried compile but I get an error: `System.Windows.Forms.Label' does not contain a definition for 'height' and no extension method 'height' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Label' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Thanks. I fixed. But and `label.MousePosition` how to fix it?

Comment: I get now: `Error 1 Member 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.MousePosition.get' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead`

Comment: Ah right, in that case the first line of my code should be: `Point cursor = label.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);`

Comment: Well, I can compile now. Thanks. But I'm getting `false` when the mouse are on label... 

`public static bool FocusTest(this Label label)
        {
            Point cursor = label.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition); 
            return !(cursor.X >= 0 && cursor.X <= label.Width && cursor.Y >= 0 && cursor.Y <= label.Height);
        }`

Comment: Yes, you should get `false` when the mouse is over the label. So long as you're getting `true` when it isn't, that's what's supposed to happen.

Answer (score 0):

`Label` can never have focus(*).  Respond to the mouse over event and manually track if the user is hovering and do your logic on that.

*not technically true see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5692661/426894)