# Label selection via Tab key

Tags: c#

I have multiple Labels & Text Boxes in my form. When the user tabs through the form, the focus never gets to Labels.
Text Boxes get focus and the cursor is shown in them, but there's no focus rectangle on Text Boxes.

If am right, the default Windows behavior is not to make Labels selectable via focus rectangle.

Is there a way of getting the focus on Labels via showing a focus rectangle around it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Could Label get a focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692620/could-label-get-a-focus)

Comment: No, you cannot give focus to a label.

Comment: May I ask what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot give focus to a label in c#, you give focus to controls the user can edit.

Comment: Yes and no. The `Label` control does have a `Focus()` method, however `ControlStyles.Selectable` is `false`. So since it's not selectable, it doesn't receive input, nothing really happens when it has focus. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx